# Dynamic chart in Excel that show user-selected time series

Tags: excel, dynamic, charts

I'm trying to create a chart in Excel (without VBA) where the user can select which time series are shown in the chart. My issue is that I can't figure out how to do this without VBA.

For example, I want to create a chart where the user can decide which of the time series Bananas, Apples and Oranges to show in the chart by marking them with an x (data is in sheet called Fruits). Any suggestions how to make this work? I tried to make an if-statement and link the cell to chart (e.g. IF(A2="x",B2,"") but this doesn't work.

```
    X-values            Y-values               Show

    Fruits!Banana_date  Fruits!Banana_sale     x

    Fruits!Apple_date   Fruits!Apple_sale

    Fruits!Orange_date  Fruits!Orange_sale     x
```

Comment: If you have a chart tied to a table, where you can sort the table, it should allow you to select specific data, where your chart shows only visible data.  You could also do somethign similar with slicers and pivot tables, where you can provide a combobox to support which data is visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two ways.

First: In Excel 2013 and later, there are three small "skittles" floating beside the chart. The third is a filter button. Click it, and you get checkboxes for the series and for the categories. The user can check and uncheck to display what they want.

[image: Chart Filter Button and Checkboxes]

Second: Set up the data like shown. Column A has the Dates. Columns B:D have the raw data for apples, bananas, and oranges.

I've placed checkboxes over cells B2:D2 (Developer tab > Controls > Insert > Form Controls > Checkbox. Each checkbox uses the cell above it as its linked cell.

Columns E:G have the plot data for the fruits. In cell E3, the formula is `=IF(B$1,B3,NA())`, and this fills the rest of these rows and columns.

Select A2:A19, then hold Ctrl while selecting E2:E19, so both areas are selected, and insert a line chart.

[image: Interactive Chart Filter with Checkboxes]

When you uncheck a checkbox, the cell above it changes from TRUE to FALSE, and the corresponding plot data column fills with #N/A values, which will not be plotted in the chart.

[image: Interactive Chart Filter with Checkboxes]

Comment: thanks for the two suggestions and good explanation with the examples

Answer (score -2):

You can make graph from temp table with =if(show=1;vlookup(X;X-Y;2;"")) and make graph from temp table.

[Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hfNKF.png)

Comment: This isn't detailed enough to enable anyone to implement it.